# How to add alias for extension namespace in wikimedia?

Tags: lua, mediawiki, scribunto

I am trying to create my custom copy of italian wikipedia from the dump.

I encounter the problem with some of extensions.

I have got the error:

> Lua error in package.lua at line 80: module 'Modulo:String' not found.

The problem is that there is no 'Modulo:String' in my copy, but there is 'Module:String'.

I have tried to add alias for this namespace in my LocalSettings.php, as I did for categories, but for modules it didn't help.

```
$wgNamespaceAliases['Categoria'] = NS_CATEGORY; //this helped for categories
$wgNamespaceAliases['Modulo'] = NS_MODULE; //this does not work
```

Module namespace is part of Scribunto default namespace.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_default_namespaces

How to solve the Lua error with loading modules?

Comment: I am not familiar with that set of applications, but: do you have a write access to `package.lua`? It sounds like you need to fix a typo in there for any of it to work. Alternatively, try renaming your copy’s `Module` to `Modulo`, but that would likely just break other things. It will need to be solved in Lua, not with an alias elsewhere.

Comment: Unrelated: in the edit queue, I came across a question that you voted on in triage. Wrong choice. Please: study the help for triage really carefully, and avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. ( I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20882811 ). Please understand that your votes have consequences and be more careful about your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual set of namespace aliases for Italian Wikipedia is [(1)](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/g/operations/mediawiki-config/+/master/wmf-config/InitialiseSettings.php#3882); `Categoria` and `Modulo` are translations. To use them, just set [`$wgLanguageCode`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgLanguageCode) to `it`.

(I'm not sure why setting `Modulo` as an alias does not work; in theory it should. But it's not the easy way to set up a mirror.)